# Resetting target values in a composite effect

Tags: apache-flex, effects

We need to be able to handle a "playable" (play/pause/seek) effect in which the nature of the effect cannot be determined at compile time.

The problem we are running into is resetting the target(s) state after the effect has completed. If we manually drag the seek slider back to the beginning, everything works fine. However, if we set the playheadTime of the composite effect back to 0, the effected targets retain their original value until the playheadTime gets to the correct position to effect the target.

Here is a simplified (as much as I could) test case with view source enabled:

http://www.openbaseinteractive.com/_tmp/PlayableEffectTest/

The problem is demonstrated if you let it play to the end, and then hit the play button to start it over.

What is the best way to go about manually resetting the target values given that the exact nature of the effect is unknown?

Many thanks for your time!

*edit*

I forgot to mention we are using Flex 4.5 preview release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's a little kludgy, but I was able to accomplish this by calling some internal methods on the effect to capture the start values, then assigned those values to the targets on a reset.

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;

private var _propertyChangesArray:Array;

protected function captureStartValues(effect:Object):void
{
    effect.captureStartValues();
    _propertyChangesArray = effect.propertyChangesArray;
}

protected function reset(effect:Object):void
{
    for each(var change:PropertyChanges in _propertyChangesArray)
    {
        var target:Object = change.target;

        for(var p:String in change.start)
        {
            if(target.hasOwnProperty(p))
            {
                var startVal:* = change.start[p];
                var endVal:* = target[p];

                if(!isNaN(startVal) && startVal != endVal)
                {
                    target[p] = startVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    effect.playheadTime = 0;
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to accomplish this, but it seems to be working so far. I am absolutely open to suggestions for a better method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
effect.reverse()
```

More info

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/IEffect.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/IEffect.html#reverse()

Comment: That just plays the effect in reverse. I need to start it over and play from the beginning.

Comment: @drkstr i did not understand, from the original post said you wanted to play the effect from the beginning; only that you wanted to set the elements back to their initial values.  Using effect.reverse() should do that.  Storing, and resetting the initial values (as stated in your own answer) seems like a viable option.

Comment: I suppose it would be. Thank you for the suggestion. :)